# How i can write the results in a file

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I am trying to write the results of my program in a file but i do not know why its does not write nothing.

I have done a program and it creates a file but when I open the file, it is empty. What i have done wrong?

```
MongoClient mongoClient;
DB db;

mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
db = mongoClient.getDB("behaviourDB_areas");  

DBCollection cEvent = db.getCollection("events_Searching");                                     
File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Nikos\\Documents\\Apotelesmata\\file1.txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter (file);    

 BasicDBObject orderBy = new BasicDBObject();
 orderBy.put("timeStamp",1);

 DBCursor cursorEvents = null;

 BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
 searchQuery.put("user_id", "55b20db905f333defea9827f");

 cursorEvents = cEvent.find(searchQuery).sort(orderBy);

 int count = 1;
 int start = 1;
 String timeStartOld = null;

 while (cursorEvents.hasNext()) {

    DBObject documentInEventCollection = cursorEvents.next();

    if("pageLoad".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))){ 

        writer.println("URL(" + count + "): " + documentInEventCollection.get("url").toString());
        //System.out.println("time-start(" + start + "): " + documentInEventCollection.get("timeStamp").toString());
        count++;
        start++;

        try {
           String timeStart = (documentInEventCollection.get("timeStamp").toString());

           if(timeStartOld==null){
               timeStartOld = timeStart;
               continue;
           }

           SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM;HH:mm:ss");

           Date d1 = null;
           Date d2 = null;

           d1 = format.parse(timeStartOld);
           d2 = format.parse(timeStart);

           //in milliseconds
           long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

           long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
           long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
           long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
           long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

           writer.println(diffDays + " days, ");
           writer.println(diffHours + " hours, ");
           writer.println(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
           writer.println(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

           timeStartOld = timeStart;

      } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  writer.close();
}   
mongoClient.close();
```

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - strip out all of the unnecessary code (and all of the 2+ lines of vertical whitespace) from here until you are left with the minimum amount of code which reproduces the problem. This is almost certainly not minimal currently, because you are both reading from a MongoDB and trying to write to a file. Do these two things work independently?

Comment: that sysout under the `writer.println` will execute if uncommented? if not check the logic actually goes inside the main if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if the below statement is getting printed in console.

```
System.out.println("time-start(" + start + "): " + documentInEventCollection.get("timeStamp").toString());
```

If not, execution is not entering the below `if` statement. Try some conditions where the `if` gets `true`.

```
 if("pageLoad".equals(documentInEventCollection.get("type"))){  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...finally i found a solution. Thanks again for your response and for your time.